# Recommended way to send messages between threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have read lots about python threading and the various means to 'talk' across thread boundaries.  My case seems a little different, so I would like to get advice on the best option:

Instead of having many identical worker threads waiting for items in a shared queue, I have a handful of mostly autonomous, non-daemonic threads with unique identifiers going about their business. These threads do not block and normally do not care about each other. They sleep most of the time and wake up periodically. Occasionally, based on certain conditions, one thread needs to 'tell' another thread to do something specific - an action -, meaningful to the receiving thread. There are many different combinations of actions and recipients, so using Events for every combination seems unwieldly. The queue object seems to be the recommended way to achieve this. However, if I have a shared queue and post an item on the queue having just one recipient thread, then every other thread needs monitor the queue, pull every item, check if it is addressed to it, and put it back in the queue if it was addressed to another thread.  That seems a lot of getting and putting items from the queue for nothing. Alternatively, I could employ a 'router' thread: one shared-by-all queue plus one queue for every 'normal' thread, shared with the router thread. Normal threads only ever put items in the shared queue, the router pulls every item, inspects it and puts it on the addressee's queue. Still, a lot of putting and getting items from queues....

Are there any other ways to achieve what I need to do ?  It seems a pub-sub class is the right approach, but there is no such thread-safe module in standard python, at least to my knowledge.

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of having many identical worker threads waiting for items in a shared queue

I think this is the right approach to do this. Just remove `identical` and `shared` from the above statement. i.e.

> having many worker threads waiting for items in queues

So I would suggest using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for this approach.

> Occasionally, based on certain conditions, one thread needs to 'tell'
>   another thread to do something specific - an action, meaningful to the receiving thread.

This can be done by calling another celery task from within the calling task. All the tasks can have separate queues.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response.  After some thoughts, I have decided to use the approach of many queues and a router-thread (hub-and-spoke). Every 'normal' thread has its private queue to the router, enabling separate send and receive queues or 'channels'. The router's queue is shared by all threads (as a property) and used by 'normal' threads as a send-only-channel, ie they only post items to this queue, and only the router listens to it, ie pulls items.  Additionally, each 'normal' thread uses its own queue as a 'receive-only-channel' on which it listens and which is shared only with the router. Threads register themselves with the router on the router queue/channel, the router maintains a list of registered threads including their queues, so it can send an item to a specific thread after its registration.

This means that peer to peer communication is not possible, all communication is sent via the router.

There are several reasons I did it this way:
1. There is no logic in the thread for checking if an item is addressed to 'me', making the code simpler and no constant pulling, checking and re-putting of items on one shared queue. Threads only listen on their queue, when a message arrives the thread can be sure that the message is addressed to it, including the router itself.
2. The router can act as a message bus, do vocabulary translation and has the possibility to address messages to external programs or hosts.
3. Threads don't need to know anything about other threads capabilities, ie they just speak the language of the router.  In a peer-to-peer world, all peers must be able to understand each other, and since my threads are of many different classes, I would have to teach each class all other classes' vocabulary.

Hope this helps someone some day when faced with a similar challenge.

Comment: I support the approach of Celery. It has support for every thing you required and it is simpler because it handles the threads creation. This is a far better approach than using a router, because these means you have to deal with synchronisation

Comment: I assume this is for a single app so there is no need for TCP communication. Implementation of hub-and-spoke in single app using queue.Queue is faster and simpler and more reliable than celery with one of it's backends.